Borel $\sigma$-field and the product $\sigma$-field
I have a question about the proof of lemma 1.5 of the textbook Measure Theory, Probability, and Stochastic Processes by Le Gall.
Lemma 1.5: Suppose that $E$ and $F$ are separable metric spaces, and equip the product $E \times F$ with the product topology. Then $\mathcal{B}(E \times F) = \mathcal{B}(E) \otimes \mathcal{B}(F)$.
My question is: when the proof is proving $\mathcal{B}(E) \otimes \mathcal{B}(F) \subset \mathcal{B}(E \times F)$, it first fixes an open subset $B$ of $F$. Then the proof directly claims the class of all sets $A \in \mathcal{B}(E)$ such that $A \times B \in \mathcal{B}(E \times F)$ contains all open subsets of E, and is easily checked to be a σ-field. However, I don't understand why such a claim holds. Why does this class of sets contain all open subsets of $E$?

If $A \subset E$ and $B \subset F$ are both open, then $A \times B \subset E \times F$ is open and thus $A \times B \in \mathcal{B}(E \times F)$.

Hi Gao, where can I find the proof that if $A$ and $B$ are open sets, then $A \times B$ is open? Thanks.

What do you mean? This is literally the definition of product topology (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology). If you’re unaware of this, I’d suggest reviewing general topology first before continuing with measure theory.
